# How to keep the Camera running when Modal is ontop

Tags: ios, camera, uikit

I noticed that if I have a view showing the output of the camera. And then I do a present modal view controller, that covers the entire screen. The camera stops in the background. I am taking the camera frames to stream them online, but when I present a modal, I stop getting frames and the content being streamed is black. I fixed this by using a thirdparty modal presenter that shows a viewcontroller as modal but in smaller size, and the background gets blur effect, so the camera keeps running. Is there a way to maintain the camera active when a modal is on top covering the entire screen?

Comment: An AVCaptureSession does not depend on the preview being displayed, AFAIK. Are you sure your AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput are not released when your first ViewController disappear?

Comment: @CharlesThierry yeah im pretty sure. Im using GPUImage Library to display de previewLayer.